# differentiate hooks and filters on the same page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I've simplified my woocommerce by putting my cart and checkout all in one page.  The annoying part of this is how to differentiate hooks and filters.  Every example I see uses a page check like:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'turn_shipping_off_on_cart_view_only' ) ){
    function turn_shipping_off_on_cart_view_only(){
        if ( is_cart() ){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'turn_shipping_off_on_cart_view_only');
```

The problem is with the cart and the checkout on the same page the above always evaluates false and turns off the shipping prompt.

**edit**

Though the subject of this is woocommerce, I feel it is on topic, as the general behavior of hooks and page checks are the same no matter what plugin is being used.

Comment: I believe the [WordPress Debug  Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) shows all the hooks that run when a page loads.